# Why won't my undo button work in android java?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I have an image which a user can paint on in my android application. I decided to add an undo button to it so the user can cancel mistakes. I made it so that when the user draws on the screen, it saves the bitmap to an array. Then when the undo button is pressed, it changes the image to the last bitmap in the array. However, this just keeps setting the image to whatever the current image is (i.e. it doesn't change it at all).

```
  public class edit extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
float MoveX,MoveY,DownY,DownX,UpY=0,UpX ;
List<Bitmap> undos = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
   final  ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    final Button buttonchoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonchoose);
    buttonchoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    final RelativeLayout ViewX = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RLXV);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = ViewX.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ViewX.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            Intent intent7 = getIntent();
            String bitmapXY = (String) intent7.getExtras().get("BitmapImage");
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/" + bitmapXY,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                            try {
                                int ViewWidth = ViewX.getMeasuredWidth();
                                JSONObject photos = response.getJSONObject();
                                JSONArray linkY = photos.optJSONArray("images");
                                final JSONObject linkO = linkY.optJSONObject(0);
                                final String link2 = linkO.optString("source");
                                URL LINKF = new URL(link2);
                                connection = (HttpURLConnection) LINKF.openConnection();
                                connection.setDoInput(true);
                                connection.connect();
                                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                                float HH = (float) bitmap.getHeight();
                                float WW = (float) bitmap.getWidth();
                                float ViewWidthX = (float) ViewWidth;
                                float height = (HH / WW) * ViewWidthX;

                                Bitmap bitmapF = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, ViewWidth, Math.round(height), false);
                               final  ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
                                image1.setImageBitmap(bitmapF);
    undos.add(bitmapF);
                                image1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

                                        float dw = d.getWidth();
                                        float dh = d.getHeight();
                                        float x = event.getX();
                                         float y = event.getY();
      float r = 2;

                                        Bitmap BTX = ((BitmapDrawable)image1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(BTX);

                                       canvas.drawBitmap(BTX,0,0,null);
                                        Paint paint1 = new Paint();
                                      int bg1 =  buttonchoose.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
                                        ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) buttonchoose.getBackground();
                                        int bg2 =buttonColor.getColor();
                                        paint1.setColor(bg2);
                                        paint1.setShadowLayer(5, 2, 2, bg2);
                                        paint1.setStrokeWidth(20);


        switch(event.getAction()){

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
 DownY = event.getY();
  DownX = event.getX();
    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    MoveY = event.getY();
MoveX = event.getX();
    canvas.drawLine(DownX, DownY, MoveX, MoveY, paint1);
    image1.invalidate();
    DownX = MoveX;
    DownY=MoveY;

    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    UpY = event.getY();
    UpX = event.getX();
    canvas.drawLine(DownX, DownY, UpX, UpY, paint1);
    image1.invalidate();
    Bitmap BTXYZ = ((BitmapDrawable)image1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    break;

 }

                                        return true;
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "images");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();






        }
    });

}






@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonchoose:
        final ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker(edit.this, 0, 0, 0);
     /* Show color picker dialog */
        cp.show();

/* On Click listener for the dialog, when the user select the color */
        Button okColor = (Button) cp.findViewById(R.id.okColorButton);
        okColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            /* You can get single channel (value 0-255) */
                int selectedColorR = cp.getRed();
                int selectedColorG = cp.getGreen();
                int selectedColorB = cp.getBlue();

            /* Or the android RGB Color (see the android Color class reference) */
                int selectedColorRGB = cp.getColor();
                Button buttonchoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonchoose);
                buttonchoose.setText("");
                buttonchoose.setBackgroundColor(selectedColorRGB);
                cp.dismiss();
            }
        });
        break;
      case R.id.imageButton2:

         int newImage = undos.size();
          Log.e("Lenght of Array",""+newImage);
          if(newImage >=1) {
              Bitmap newImage2 = undos.get(newImage-2);
              ImageView IMGXV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
              IMGXV.setImageBitmap(newImage2);

              undos.remove(newImage-1);
          }
          break;
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: are you sure your if condition is executing?

Comment: Ya, I got it to log the lenght of the array undos, and after i click the undo button twice it reduces by one, meaning the if statement is running

Answer (score 0):

Try this exact code -

```
case R.id.imageButton2:

      if(undos.size() > 0) {
          Bitmap newImage2 = undos.remove(undos.size() - 1);
          ImageView IMGXV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
          IMGXV.setImageBitmap(newImage2);
      }
      break;
```

**EDIT** Added an extra line in onGlobalLayout(), try this -

```
Bitmap bitmapF = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, ViewWidth, Math.round(height), false);
final  ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
image1.setImageBitmap(bitmapF);
//The extra line before adding bitmap to arraylist.
Bitmap bitmapFcopy = bitmapFcopy.copy(bitmapFcopy.getConfig(), true);
undos.add(bitmapFcopy);
```

**EDIT 2**

```
public class edit extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

//Declare the imageview here and access this everywhere.
ImageView image1;
float MoveX,MoveY,DownY,DownX,UpY=0,UpX ;
List<Bitmap> undos = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

   //Get the reference here
   image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
   final  ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    final Button buttonchoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonchoose);
    buttonchoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    final RelativeLayout ViewX = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RLXV);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = ViewX.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ViewX.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            Intent intent7 = getIntent();
            String bitmapXY = (String) intent7.getExtras().get("BitmapImage");
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/" + bitmapXY,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                            try {
                                int ViewWidth = ViewX.getMeasuredWidth();
                                JSONObject photos = response.getJSONObject();
                                JSONArray linkY = photos.optJSONArray("images");
                                final JSONObject linkO = linkY.optJSONObject(0);
                                final String link2 = linkO.optString("source");
                                URL LINKF = new URL(link2);
                                connection = (HttpURLConnection) LINKF.openConnection();
                                connection.setDoInput(true);
                                connection.connect();
                                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                                float HH = (float) bitmap.getHeight();
                                float WW = (float) bitmap.getWidth();
                                float ViewWidthX = (float) ViewWidth;
                                float height = (HH / WW) * ViewWidthX;

                                Bitmap bitmapF = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, ViewWidth, Math.round(height), false);

                                //Remove from here and declare this in onCreate() and don't make it final                                   
                                //final ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
                                image1.setImageBitmap(bitmapF);
    undos.add(bitmapF);
                                image1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

                                        float dw = d.getWidth();
                                        float dh = d.getHeight();
                                        float x = event.getX();
                                         float y = event.getY();
      float r = 2;

                                        Bitmap BTX = ((BitmapDrawable)image1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(BTX);

                                       canvas.drawBitmap(BTX,0,0,null);
                                        Paint paint1 = new Paint();
                                      int bg1 =  buttonchoose.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
                                        ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) buttonchoose.getBackground();
                                        int bg2 =buttonColor.getColor();
                                        paint1.setColor(bg2);
                                        paint1.setShadowLayer(5, 2, 2, bg2);
                                        paint1.setStrokeWidth(20);


        switch(event.getAction()){

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
 DownY = event.getY();
  DownX = event.getX();
    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    MoveY = event.getY();
MoveX = event.getX();
    canvas.drawLine(DownX, DownY, MoveX, MoveY, paint1);
    image1.invalidate();
    DownX = MoveX;
    DownY=MoveY;

    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    UpY = event.getY();
    UpX = event.getX();
    canvas.drawLine(DownX, DownY, UpX, UpY, paint1);
    image1.invalidate();
    Bitmap BTXYZ = ((BitmapDrawable)image1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    break;

 }

                                        return true;
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "images");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();






        }
    });

}






@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonchoose:
        final ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker(edit.this, 0, 0, 0);
     /* Show color picker dialog */
        cp.show();

/* On Click listener for the dialog, when the user select the color */
        Button okColor = (Button) cp.findViewById(R.id.okColorButton);
        okColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            /* You can get single channel (value 0-255) */
                int selectedColorR = cp.getRed();
                int selectedColorG = cp.getGreen();
                int selectedColorB = cp.getBlue();

            /* Or the android RGB Color (see the android Color class reference) */
                int selectedColorRGB = cp.getColor();
                Button buttonchoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonchoose);
                buttonchoose.setText("");
                buttonchoose.setBackgroundColor(selectedColorRGB);
                cp.dismiss();
            }
        });
        break;
      case R.id.imageButton2:

         int newImage = undos.size();
          Log.e("Lenght of Array",""+newImage);
          if(newImage >=1) {
              Bitmap newImage2 = undos.get(newImage-2);
              //Don't take reference again here
              //ImageView IMGXV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
              image1.setImageBitmap(newImage2);

              undos.remove(newImage-1);
          }
          break;
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: then probably there's a problem somewhere else. Try posting your full code.

Comment: @GarethPower check my updated answer and sorry can't try the code as don't have access to Android Studio right now.

Comment: No problem, but it still doesn't work. I have done some testing and it seems as if it only changes the image bitmap to the current image bitmap, no matter which bitmap i choose from the undos list.

Comment: @GarethPower I made some important changes. Try using this whole code. Check if you are able to set some other image now. Don't make the ImageView final and use 'image1' reference everywhere to access the ImageView.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working. I would say it is something got to do with the ArrayList, because I did testing and it only sets the image to the current bitmap, no other ones